# Is there a way to translate the Sacks Spiral into a triangle?

Tags: prime-numbers

The sacks spiral is our natural number system written in the form of a spiral and it highlights the primes which seem to fall on certain curves within the spiral. I am interested to know if there is a way to translate the sacks spiral into a triangle where the curves become parallel with the hypotenuse.

Similar to the link below except rather than peeling back the circle with smaller circles you peel it back by the curves of the spiral?

[enter link description here](http://www.amsi.org.au/teacher_modules/B5/B5g8.png)

[enter link description here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Sacks_spiral.svg/2000px-Sacks_spiral.svg.png)